# how to get data from xml file with the (ID) number in android studio

Tags: javascript, java, xml, android-studio, xml-parsing

```
 <Chapter ChapterID="1" ChapterName="The Opening">
    <Verse VerseID="1"><![CDATA[text1 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="2"><![CDATA[text2 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="3"><![CDATA[text3 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="4"><![CDATA[text4 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="5"><![CDATA[text5 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="6"><![CDATA[text6 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="7"><![CDATA[text7 ]]></Verse>
</Chapter>
<Chapter ChapterID="2" ChapterName="The main">
    <Verse VerseID="1"><![CDATA[text1 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="2"><![CDATA[text2 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="3"><![CDATA[text3 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="4"><![CDATA[text4 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="5"><![CDATA[text5 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="6"><![CDATA[text6 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="7"><![CDATA[text7 ]]></Verse>
</Chapter>
<Chapter ChapterID="3" ChapterName="The ending">
    <Verse VerseID="1"><![CDATA[text1 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="2"><![CDATA[text2 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="3"><![CDATA[text3 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="4"><![CDATA[text4 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="5"><![CDATA[text5 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="6"><![CDATA[text6 ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="7"><![CDATA[text7 ]]></Verse>
</Chapter>
```

so that was the XML file > As you can see, each Chapter contains words and an id for it

what i want to do it to get all the text from a chapter by its id in java

for example some thing like  :

```
get Chapter.ChapterID = (int)
```

and then get all the text from that Chapter with that id

I know I am bad at asking the question or idea I want
but...
I hope the idea arrived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you take a look at different XML Parsing Libaries. There exists a lot of different, helpful tutorials (for example https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-xml-parser-tutorial).
If you don't understand some of the explanation or if you get problems while coding, you can ask a new question. 
One more thing, try to search for a solution first, before asking at stackoverflow. A lot of questions which you might have, have been already been answered in the past on stackoverflow or on similar forums/websites.